# How could I display pdf in my application

Tags: android, pdf

Hi I used below codes to display pdf in my application. But it quits my applications and display pdf in webbrowser. But I want to display it in my application and display backbutton below the my applications. So how could I change these codes. Thanks alot.

```
 String fullPath = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16f9Z9VbJmCc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl";
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fullPath));
          startActivity( browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your webview to display pdf

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "your file.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```